# Find your friends from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way I can list the users that are registered on my site and are friends with the authenticated facebook user I have visiting my site?

Sort of like, 'These are your friends who are already registered to our website'

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't Facebook offer a plugin or embedded something-or-other for this sort of thing?

Comment: there is a way see graph.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to integrate facebook's graph API, then compare email addresses.  You will be forced to have one of those "allow access" forms pop-up from facebook since you'll need to access at least globally public information from the user's profile

So you can compare facebook ID's if the visitor is registered and all the friends who you want to bring up are as well, or compare email addresses if not every user on your site is logging in with facebook.  Either way you're going to be reading the graph API for a little while.

Hope this helped

Comment: I thought that Facebook only provides a @facebook.com mail of the user and then uses a mail forward to send the user the emails..

Comment: it depends on the user's security settings, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for instance if you retrieved my info, it wouldn't even give an email

Comment: but how do you get the user's *friend's* email addresses? Iirc this is not available -- I'm stuck on this too :(